# MySQL Update with phrase?

Tags: mysql, wordpress, replace

I am using `WordPress/MySQ`L for blog system. And I want to change all phrases `"Advanced Test System"` to `"Best Test System"`, so I use the following statement on the `WordPress` database(`MySQL` Database):

```
UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content=(REPLACE (post_content, 'Advanced Test System','Best Test System'));
```

Is that correct? Will the replace work for a phrase even if it contains spaces?

Comment: Just replace `Advanced` word with `Best`

Comment: Would it not be quicker to test than to ask?

Comment: @Strawberry: I just run the query and it seems to work properly. But I am not sure since it is impossible to check thousands of files manually. So I ask here for verification purpose.

Comment: You only have to 'test' for one, right?

Answer (score 0):

you can do like this

```
UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = replace(post_content, 'Advanced Test System', 'Best Test System');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = replace(post_content, 'Advanced Test System', 'Best Test System');
```